# Java designing tuning parameter object

Tags: java, machine-learning

I'm implementing a machine learning pipeline in Java. As part of it I have a class representing my tuning parameters. In the end, I have to run over all pairs of tuning parameters and calculating the accuracy. For example, a tuning parameter could be the k of k-nearest neighbours raning from 1 to 9.

First, which data structure is best to store the tuning parameters? Each tuning parameter is associated with a list of possible values. The value of the  parameters are mostly doubles (or ints) but not only. They could also be Strings.

Second, I would like to create some sort of iterator for this object. A method getNextPair() should return the next set of tuning parameters until hasNext() returns false. In this way I can iterate over it with a single while loop (no nested for loops).

How can I calculate all pairs of tuning parameters for the getNextPair() and hasNext() methods? Of course this highly depends on the data structure used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using Multimaps. It is similar to a Map, where you can have multiple values for one key.

Guava implements Multimaps and you can iterate over it in a single loop, as illustrated below:

```
    Multimap<String, Double> mm = ArrayListMultimap.create();

    mm.put("alpha", 0.0);
    mm.put("alpha", 0.7);
    mm.put("alpha", 0.9);

    for (double lambda = 0.0; lambda < 2.0; lambda += .25)
        mm.put("lambda", lambda);


    List<Double> A = (List<Double>)mm.get("alpha"); 
    System.out.println(A);
    System.out.println("Number of values for alpha: " + A.size());

    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> e : mm.entries()) 
        System.out.println(e);

    System.out.println("Number of elements:" + mm.entries().size());
```

There is a good tutorial [there](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/guava/guava_multimap.htm). I hope it helps.